# How to order by latest date record from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my full code:

```
<?php $sid = $_SESSION['userid'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.*
    FROM tableA
    LEFT JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.tableAuserid = tableB.tableAuserid
    LEFT JOIN tableC
    ON tableA.tableAuserid = tableC.tableCuserid
    WHERE tableA.tableAuserid = ?
    ;
");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $sid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$columns = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach($columns as $column):
$tableAdate = $column['tableAdate'];
$tableBdate = $column['tableBdate'];
$tableCdate = $column['tableCdate'];
    if ($tableAdate): ?>
        <div><?php echo $tableAdate; ?></div>
    <?php endif;
    if ($tableBdate): ?>
        <div><?php echo $tableBdate; ?></div>
    <?php endif;
    if ($tableCdate): ?>
        <div><?php echo $tableCdate; ?></div>
    <?php endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

My 3 database tables are: `tableA`:

```
tableAid | tableAuserid | tableAdate
    1    |     44       | 2018-07-13 11:09:11
    2    |     44       | 2019-05-23 01:21:29
```

`tableB`:

```
tableBid | tableBuserid | tableBdate
    1    |     44       | 2019-08-11 17:41:01
```

And `tableC`:

```
tableCid | tableCuserid | tableCdate
    1    |     44       | 2014-03-14 09:18:16
```

This is the result that's currently being echoed from my code:

```
2018-07-13 11:09:11
2019-08-11 17:41:01
2014-03-14 09:18:16
2019-05-23 01:21:29
2019-08-11 17:41:01
2014-03-14 09:18:16
```

But this is the result I *want achieved* from the code:

```
2019-08-11 17:41:01 (tableB)
2019-05-23 01:21:29 (tableA)
2018-07-13 11:09:11 (tableA)
2014-03-14 09:18:16 (tableC)
```

Basically each record must be retrieved with no duplicate values, result must be determined by the $_SESSION['userid'] variable, `ORDER` arrangement of SQL code must be by the latest date `DESC` of all dates combined from all 3 tables. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `foreach($columns` < where is that variable taking its data from?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner From this line right before it: `$columns = $stmt->fetchAll();`. Sorry I just reedited my code and corrected the mistake.

Comment: Feeling like this could all be done in SQL...? If not just with ORDER BY then a conditional?

Comment: @ficuscr But `ORDER BY tableA.tableAdate AND tableB.tableBdate AND tableC.tableCdate` won't work though?

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, you can use GROUP BY and/or DISTINCT in SELECT.

Comment: @misner3456 not sure I get the logic, but ordering on three columns is as simple as `ORDER BY cola, colb, colc;`. I'm sure it could be done with sub-selects (or a union). Probably preferable to doing that logic with PHP. Let the database do what it excels at.

Comment: @ficuscr I showed on the last code snippet how I want the result to look like. I'm working with FunkFortyNiner's suggestion atm

Comment: Why are there multiple tables?

Comment: @Strawberry Um.. so it's not common for people to retrieve data from multiple tables?

Comment: No. Vanishingly rare. It usually points to poor design.

Comment: @Strawberry Wait what. So what if someone had a `users` table with 5 columns and a `orders` table with 5 columns and then a `posts` table with 5 columns? You wouldn't bundle 15 columns in one single table right

Comment: @Strawberry I gather  you mean 3 tables with the same sets of information, not 3 different tables.   relational databases are still heavily in use (as in, today)

Comment: Perhaps we can set aside these sorts of inane questions. I gather we all agree what we're talking about.

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry that I didn't respond to you on time, I was working with other people's suggestions. And no, all 3 tables do not contain the same information as you assume. The date column is already proof of that. These are merely dummy tables.

Comment: I guess in that case I don't follow; we can only go on the information provided.

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe because you saw that typo I made as commented by KlienblatMoshe with that last join on tableC, which I just fixed. Either way, fixing the typo wasn't a solution. Ficusr's answer resolved everything.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but glad you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feel like I am missing some nuance of the question but perhaps not. Lot's of ways to accomplish this.

The following [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) allows for a fair amount of flexibility, that is, the ability to refine criteria per table and still sort on the SQL side of things.

```
SELECT tId, tUserId, tDate FROM tableA WHERE tUserId = ?
UNION ALL 
SELECT tId, tUserId, tDate FROM tableB WHERE tUserId = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT tId, tUserId, tDate FROM tableC WHERE tUserId = ?
ORDER BY tDate DESC;
```

I honestly don't write many of these. Maybe in large part because of ORMs (something to look into), or as the conversation has leaned towards, design. Your first take with the `left join` is the format of probably 95% of the queries I write.  Anyway though, there is no reason not to use a union for certain reporting needs. Maybe even create a [`view`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-syntax.html) **gasp**.

Comment: you beat me to it

Comment: @nomistic :)  Still feel like I'm glossing over something though.

Comment: he's going to actually need to rename the dates to be the same alias I believe first.    This to me looks like a classic case of someone trying to get the application layer to do what belongs to the db

Comment: @ficuscr Yes, Perfect! This fixed everything! I tried using the WHERE with UNION ALL before but did it in the wrong format - I didn't know it had to be done this way. Kept assuming the WHERE clause had to be used only once as with JOINS. Otherwise, Thank you!

Comment: @nomistic You're right. These are just dummy tables, but I changed all the column names based on table and everything's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

first your SQL is not correct tableB dose not have the column tableB.tableAuserid

```
  SELECT tableA.*, tableB.*, tableC.*
  FROM tableA
  LEFT JOIN tableB
  ON tableA.tableAuserid = tableB.tableBuserid
  LEFT JOIN tableC
  ON tableA.tableAuserid = tableC.tableCuserid
  WHERE tableA.tableAuserid = 44
  ORDER BY tableAdate desc, tableBdate desc, tableCdate DESC
```

Comment: That was a typo since these are dummy tables. And I also didn't want duplicates, which ficusr's answer resolved. But thanks for your solution also